# Compile old Delphi and C++ Builder source code

Tags: ide

I have old projects that I need to compile again. There were developed on Borland Delphi 3 and Borland C++ Builder (I'm not sure if it was 1.0 or 4.0)

What do you recommend to do this? Are Delphi XE and C++ Builder CX able to import this old projects? If there is a migration tool (Open Source or commercial), it will be useful too.

Comment: No there are not but if you have a competent Delphi developer they can port it.  The port requires intelligence as the changes are not mechanical search/replace in nature. 

I would consider porting the Delphi 3 code up to Delphi 2007, the last non-unicode version, then porting to Delphi 10.1 Berlin (latest as of this date in 2016).   Moving above 2007 to 2009 or any of the XEs or the latest 10.x Seattle/Berlin requires addressing Unicode.

C++ Builder porting is much the same. A developer familiar with the IDE, the language, and the framework is generally required.

Comment: Some helpful resources:

https://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/technical-papers/delphi-unicode-migration.pdf

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38980

Comment: Grab a free copy of delphi 10.1 starter edition here while you can...

https://www.embarcadero.com/app-development-tools-store/delphi

Answer (score 3):

You will have to make changes as you go but it might be worth taking a look a [Lazarus IDE](http://www.lazarus-ide.org/) & [FreePascal](http://www.freepascal.org/)

- Free, Gratis & OpenSource
- Cross Platform
- To quote the web page: "Compatibility with TP 7.0 as well as with most versions of Delphi"

Comment: This amounts to a total rewrite as Delphi components mostly won't work inside it.  A "delphi program" depends heavily on the VCL, and the LCL itself is not highly VCL compatible, and the third party controls that most Delphi codebases depend on are not portable easily to the LCL style either.  In the end, it's so much work that you may as well consider it a rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

I am stuck behind the company firewall and can't currently view some of the sites I will mention, so I will have to update this answer this evening. I post now, because I won't be home from the office for 14 hours or more, so you might have found it before then, from what I am about to say. If so, please post here.

Much as I like Lazarus, you best bet (probably your only bet, if you use 3rd party VCL) is Delphi itself.

1) Long ago, Borland gave away Delphi for free, both on the web and on magazine covers (they also gave away for free Kylix, which was cross platform Delphi, which supported both Windows and Linux - long since abandoned, but possibly of interest, although Lazarus is almost certainly superior).

So, Goggling for something like `Delphi 7 giveaway free download` should do the trick/. I will race you to see who finds it first ;-)

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AigX7SqyMQI) appears to be a video telling you “How to get delphi 7, completely free“     Please note that , being in the office, I have not viewed this video.

I can’t check if [this one](http://www.filecluster.com/downloads/Delphi-7-Enterprise.html) is legal

You get the idea, just keep goggling.

2) Failing that, try eBay.

3) Or, if you only need to recompile once, rather than have an on-going solution, you might try a trial version of the current Delphi & import your projects (although something that old might not be supported).

4) Failing all of that, you could buy the Starter Edition (see this page for comparisons), which is still far too expensive, imo.  https://www.embarcadero.com/app-development-tools-store/delphi

I will update this evening, when I can Google without the firewall

Comment: Starter Edition is currently FREE (for next few days).

https://www.embarcadero.com/app-development-tools-store/delphi

Comment: Then I think that you ought to post that as an answer, Warren. If I were the OP, I would award it

Comment: It won't be available after september 2, so that's not really a good permanent answer.  The OP is looking for a translation tool not a free version of Delphi Starter.